# How to display only distinct records when the information displayed is already in a formula

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, distinct, formula

I already have some records displayed using a formula. But there are duplicates within those records. How do I get rid of these duplicates? I already tried the 
{table.field}=previous({table.field}) but it didn't work. Neither does Database> select distinct records. Any assistance will be much appreciated

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and the query you are using.

Comment: please provide more info! Show your work!

Comment: `Previous ({database.field}) = {database.field}` will only work if the dataset is sorted by `{database.field}`.

Comment: Can you not amend your SQL query to show only distinct records?